# Ubuntu - Where is the correct sources.list file?

Tags: unix, ubuntu, nginx

Here is my Ubuntu version

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
Release:        12.10
Codename:       quantal

I need the most up-to-date list for /etc/apt/sources.list as I had previously changed a few things around. Any idea where I can find this?

For example, right now I cannot even install nginx (apt-get install ngnix) as my distribution cannot even seem to find it!

Comment: This question would fit more to: http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely related to the fact that Ubuntu Quantal reached end of life on May 16 2014 and is no longer supported (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/05/01/ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal-reaches-end-of-life-on-may-16-2014/)

It is recommended that you upgrade of course since you will not receive any more updates. However, if you want to keep using an old version of Ubuntu, you need to change your sources.list file to point to archived repositories. You will not receive upgrades, but you will be able to install software. The process is explained here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades